# No cursor output on the sceen when typing password in terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line, input

I am in the process of trying to get a VPN started on my PC, and I have quake terminal running and that's when it would not register the keyboard when I was typing in the password for `sudo`.

So I rebooted and tried the command terminal that came with the disc, and it still will not register an entry into the password zone.

Answer (score 4):

The **Terminal** by default does not show or display characters when you type passwords, all you'll see is nothing...but your password is still being accepted and the command will still run.

[image]

Just type your password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you typed your password correctly, there should be no problems. If your password is incorrect, then you'll get the same prompt asking you to retype the password.

[image]