# Place for password is blocked

Tags: password

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No cursor output on the sceen when typing password in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195381/no-cursor-output-on-the-sceen-when-typing-password-in-terminal)

I am running Ubuntu 12-10.

This is my trouble:
When I write (for example) `sudo apt-get install Wine` in Terminal all seems ok until the
program asks for password. The problem is that the place to write is blocked by a white rectangle so writing is impossible!
Please help,   Perolof

Answer (score 1):

it's not blocked. That is security.

Just type your password and press enter.

Comment: It's so that people looking over your shoulder can't see the length of the password you typed 10 mins ago.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As usual very simple when you know the answer!!!